# How can I convert the query_set list to a list that contains the dictionary?

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

As all we know, we can use the `model_to_dict` convert the query_set to a dictionary.

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict 
u = User.objects.get(id=1)  
u_dict = model_to_dict(u)  
type(u)  
#<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>  
type(u_dict)  
#<type 'dict'>
```

But, I want to convert the query_set to a list that contains the dictionary.

```
uers = User.objects.all()
```

Here I will write a `for` loop to convert the query_set to convert to dictionary. then append to a list.

So, whether there is a convenient way to convert the query_set list to my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list(map(model_to_dict,User.objects.all()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .values

```
User.objects.values()
```

This returns a QuerySet. You can change to list by simply casting to list

```
list(User.objects.values())
```

Same can be used with `filter`: `User.objects.filter(<some filter>).values()`